# <Thinking in java> error: can not find class: Explore.class

Tags: java

I am following the book Thinking in Java (4th edition), but I am getting an exception when trying on of the examples.

Main class:

```
enum Explore { HERE, THERE }

public class Reflection {
  public static Set<String> analyze(Class<?> enumClass) {
    print("----- Analyzing " + enumClass + " -----");
    print("Interfaces:");
    for(Type t : enumClass.getGenericInterfaces())
      print(t);
    print("Base: " + enumClass.getSuperclass());
    print("Methods: ");
    Set<String> methods = new TreeSet<String>();
    for(Method m : enumClass.getMethods())
      methods.add(m.getName());
    print(methods);
    return methods;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> exploreMethods = analyze(Explore.class);
    Set<String> enumMethods = analyze(Enum.class);
    print("Explore.containsAll(Enum)? " +
      exploreMethods.containsAll(enumMethods));
    printnb("Explore.removeAll(Enum): ");
    exploreMethods.removeAll(enumMethods);
    print(exploreMethods);

    OSExecute.command("javap Explore.class "); 
  }
}
```

OSExecute.java:

```
package net.mindview.util;
import java.io.*;

public class OSExecute {
  public static void command(String command) {
    boolean err = false;
    try {
      Process process =
        new ProcessBuilder(command.split(" ")).start();
      BufferedReader results = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
      String s;
      while((s = results.readLine())!= null)
        System.out.println(s);
      BufferedReader errors = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
      // Report errors and return nonzero value
      // to calling process if there are problems:
      while((s = errors.readLine())!= null) {
        System.err.println(s);
        err = true;
      }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      // Compensate for Windows 2000, which throws an
      // exception for the default command line:
      if(!command.startsWith("CMD /C"))
        command("CMD /C " + command);
      else
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if(err)
      //Here it throws the exception:
      throw new OSExecuteException("Errors executing " +
        command);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
----- Analyzing class Explore -----
Interfaces 
Base: class java.lang.Enum
Methods: 
[compareTo, equals, getClass, getDeclaringClass, hashCode, name, notify, notifyAll, ordinal, toString, valueOf, values, wait]
----- Analyzing class java.lang.Enum -----
Interfaces:
java.lang.Comparable<E>
interface java.io.Serializable
Base: class java.lang.Object
Methods: 
[compareTo, equals, getClass, getDeclaringClass, hashCode, name, notify, notifyAll, ordinal, toString, valueOf, wait]
Explore.containsAll(Enum)? true
Explore.removeAll(Enum): [values]
Error: cannot find class Explore.class
Exception in thread "main" net.mindview.util.OSExecuteException: 
    at net.mindview.util.OSExecute.command(OSExecute.java:35)
    at Reflection.main(Reflection.java:33)**
```

Comment: even i do these main method test:                                                                                public class OSExecute {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  command("javap OSExecute");
 }
  public static void command(String command) {
    boolean err = false;
   ......................
}

Comment: @ChetanKinger  stackoverflow editing check can not pass my question

Comment: The command javap cannot find the class `Explore`. Is this class in the default package? You should try to get `javap Explore.class` to run on the command line (probably fixing classpath or package), it has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @Philipp Wendler   you are right!it works ! thanks a lot!!    // Decompile the code for the enum:
    OSExecute.command("javap D:/eclipse_workspace/thinking/bin/Explore.class ");

Answer (score 1):

The command javap cannot find the class Explore. Is this class in the default package? You should try to get javap Explore.class to run on the command line (probably fixing classpath or package), it has nothing to do with your code. –--  Philipp Wendler

OSExecute.command("javap D:/eclipse_workspace/thinking/bin/Explore.class ");